# Spring @PropertySource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have simple spring application.
`Spring` version is `3.2.16.RELEASE`.

Project structure is:

[image: project structure]
.

Application class looks like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ua.xxxx.spring.hometask")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);

        final SpringHomeTaskConsoleUI consoleUI = context.getBean(SpringHomeTaskConsoleUI.class);

        consoleUI.run();
    }
}
```

When I try to run it I have:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I have trying:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath*:application.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/application.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:src/main/resources/application.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath*:src/main/application.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "application.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "src/main/application.properties")
```

and other...

Resources folder is marked as resource root...
Intellij project structure is ok.

Any ideas what can be wrong?
Did I missed something?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add absolute path file location @PropertySource("file:/root/.../application.properties")

Comment: Absolute path works, but if someone pull my code he should change this path, and it's not good(

Comment: try without the value : @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

Comment: 'file:src/main/resources/application.properties' works, thanks for advice!

Comment: I also face the same issue and it works with absolute path. Any reason why it is not working with `classpath:` ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add `org.springframework.boot spring-boot-configuration-processor`.